# blazor client side calling 3rd party rest api credentials HttpClientHandler PlatformNotSupported

Tags: rest, api, credentials, blazor

I have some c# code to call a rest api of a database, and it needs the credentials to be entered as part of the api call:

```cs
public string GetezeName(string account, string readcode)
{                
    string s = "";

    credentialCache = new CredentialCache(); 
    credentialCache.Add( 
           new Uri("https://ezecontrol.com"), // request url's host
           "Digest",  // authentication type 
            new NetworkCredential(account, readcode)); 

    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request;
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://ezecontrol.com/api/status.php");
        request.Credentials = credentialCache;
        request.Method = "GET";

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {         
            Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader inx = new StreamReader(data);
            json = inx.ReadToEnd();

            response.Close();
            inx.Close();                   
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return s;
}
```

However, I need to change this to use HttpClient in C# client side blazor:

```cs
public async Task DoUpdate()
{
    try
    {
        CredentialCache credentialCache;
        string account = "xxyyzz";
        string readcode = "xxyyzz";

        credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
        credentialCache.Add(
                   new Uri("https://ezecontrol.com"), // request url's host
                   "Digest",  // authentication type 
                   new System.Net.NetworkCredential(account,readcode));

        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentialCache })
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        { 
            HttpResponseMessage msg = await client.GetAsync("https://ezecontrol.com/api/status.php");

            reply = msg.StatusCode.ToString();

            return ;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        reply = ex.Message+ex.StackTrace;

        return ;
    }
    return ;
}
```

When this is executed, `HttpClientHandler` shows a platform not supported error.

Is there any other way to do this sort of call ?

Comment: You cannot use Digest authentication on blazor wasm. You should create a web api proxy protected by jwt bearer, oauth or oidc.

Comment: I am currently trying to consume a third party API using basic authentication and it doesn't seem to work..